# C# analog type for ssize_t

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke, 32bit-64bit

I'm looking for a C# integral data type that can hold 32 bit signed values on 32-bit machines and 64-bit signed values on 64-bit machines.
The reason for this is a P/Invoke call to a C function that receives a **ssize_t** parameter.
I know I could work with preprocessor directives to "DllImport" this function in different ways for different machines (with **ints** for 32-bit machines and **longs** for 64-bit), but that would require me to build and ship for different targets, which is very undesirable.

Any other solutions to this problem are very welcome, of course :D

Comment: @Marcelo - I think your looking for `IntPtr`

Comment: The other simple solution is to always send your C code a 64-bit value.  You don't seem to indicate the reason this cannot be done.

Comment: `ssize_t` is not part of the C standard, but comes with POSIX. For C you have `intptr_t` or better `uintptr_t` that is an integer type that can hold the same information as a pointer. It must not necessarily exist (if there is no such type on a target machine) but usually it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [IntPtr type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.aspx):

> The IntPtr type is designed to be an integer whose size is platform-specific. That is, an instance of this type is expected to be 32-bits on 32-bit hardware and operating systems, and 64-bits on 64-bit hardware and operating systems.

Comment: gosh.. never thought of IntPtr as simply holding a number, my mind always looked at it as a pointer, and for that I always thought it was unsigned.. nailed it!

Comment: IntPtr is signed. If you need an unsigned type, you can use [UIntPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uintptr.aspx).

Comment: @dtb - He indicates he is looking to store signed integers.  There is also a "gotcha" when dealing with the `UIntPtr` based on some quick reading I did.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm looking for a C# integral data type that can hold 32 bit signed
>   values on 32-bit machines and 64-bit signed values on 64-bit machines.

You are looking for [`IntPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).